# Pycharm import is not working on terminal, but working on python console

Tags: python, pycharm

I came across an issue regarding import statement while learning python packaging.

I created `mul_two.py` and `mul_test1.py` inside the same directory. Inside `mul_test1.py` I imported `mul_2` function written in `mul_two.py` file

[image: Folder Structure]

`mul_two.py`

```
def mul_2(x):
    return x*2
```

`mul_test1.py`

```
from multiply.mul_two import mul_2
print(mul_2(4))
```

When I run the mul1_test1.py from Pycharm, I get correct result.

[image: Success from Pycharm Run]

But when I try to run from Terminal, I get "no module" error.

[image: Error from Pycharm Terminal]

I would like to understand the reason for this and any fix.

FYI, I just hidden my username from snapshots.

Comment: Is the directory containing your `multiply` package on the Python path? This is usually done by either installing your code as a distribution package or by ensuring that that directory is your CWD.

Comment: Also, not that `python3 ./file.py` runs `file` as a top-level module that's not part of a package. To run a module as `__main__`, use `python3 -m package.subpkg.module`.

Comment: Pycharm usually sets a "Sources" directory for the project. When opening the console it uses that sources directory for the `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @Brian I too found something similar to your comment from few other threads. But somehow I am unable to make it work. 

I tried below steps already and still not works
-- Ran "python3 mul_test1.py" from multiply directory. No luck
-- Added /path/to/multiply to PATH in bash profile and ran test again and not working

Comment: @Godwin To be clear, `PATH` is not related to the Python path. If you want Python to be able to find `multiply`, the directory _containing_ it (not the `multiply/` directory itself) needs to be on the Python path. See Abdul's comment above for how to configure Python to automatically add your source directories to `PYTHONPATH`. Failing that, you can rely on your CWD being set properly in your terminal/run configuration.

Comment: @Brian Thanks for your comments. After some more explore, I finally figured out the mistake I was doing. I tried appending subdirectory where the mul_two.py is present and not the top level directory itself to sys.path. When I modified that to top level directory, it worked.

Answer (score -1):

As they are in the same directory, you don't need the absolute path. Enough:

```py
from mul_two import mul_2
print(mul_2(4))
```

If your directory structure is:

```
- mult/
    - mul_two.py
- main.py
```

add `mult/__init__.py`so that python can see this folder as a module

## EDIT

Python doesn't know what the root of your project is, nothing tells it that your `any_name` folder is the root.

What it gives is to inform that a folder is a **module**, creating the file `__init__.py`.

When you run `python3 multiply/mult_test1.py` mult_test1 is your root

```
# example 
from calc.mul_two import mul_2  #ERROR
from mul_two import mul_2  #SUCCESS
print(mul_2(4))
```

But, if you run `python3 main.py` that folder is your root:

```
# YOUR /MULT/MULT_TEST1.PY FILE
from mult.mul_two import mul_2

def mytest():
    print(mul_2(4))

# YOUR MAIN.PY FILE
from calc.mul_test1 import mytest

mytest()
```

## REFERENCE

https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/

Comment: Yes, I know it works without absolute path. But I am trying to understand why it is not working only from Terminal, when adding the absolute path.

Comment: @Godwin I updated my answer, please see if it makes sense

Comment: I finally figured out the mistake I was doing. I tried appending subdirectory where the mul_two.py is present and not the top level directory itself to sys.path. When I modified that to top level directory, it worked.